# .htaccess subfolder no redirect correctly - Error 404

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

I have a wordpress installation in the root of my server, I wanted to use the "opensourcepos" script in a new directory called "ospos"
If I try to access the link
[www.mysite.it/ospos/](http://www.mysite.it/ospos/)
I am redirected to
[www.mysite.it/public](http://www.mysite.it/public)
with 404 error

To access the ospos installation I have to go to
[www.mysite.it/ospos/public](http://www.mysite.it/ospos/public)
only in this way everything works correctly.

Maybe there is some instruction in the ospos folder .htaccess file
which does not redirect correctly.

Code .htaccess wordpress /root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Code .htaccess root/ospos

```
# redirect to public page
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge [NC]
    RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/public/" [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>

# disable directory browsing
# For security reasons, Option all cannot be overridden.
Options +ExecCGI +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes

# prevent folder listing
IndexIgnore *

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule authz_core_module>
  # secure htaccess file
  <Files .htaccess>
    Require all denied
  </Files>

  # prevent access to PHP error log
  <Files error_log>
    Require all denied
  </Files>

  # prevent access to LICENSE
  <Files LICENSE>
    Require all denied
  </Files>

  # prevent access to csv, txt and md files
  <FilesMatch "\.(csv|txt|md|yml|json|lock)$">
    Require all denied
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
  # secure htaccess file
  <Files .htaccess>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
  </Files>

  # prevent access to PHP error log
  <Files error_log>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
  </Files>

  # prevent access to LICENSE
  <Files LICENSE>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
  </Files>

  # prevent access to csv, txt and md files
  <FilesMatch "\.(csv|txt|md|yml|json|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Code .htaccess root/ospos/public

```
RewriteEngine On

# To redirect a subdomain to a subdir because of https not supporting wildcards
# replace values between <> with your ones
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^<OSPOS subdomain>\.<my web domain>\.com$ [OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.<OSPOS subdomain>\.<my web domain>\.com$
# RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.<my web domain>\.com\/<OSPOS path>" [R=301,L]

# To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if in web root
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# if in subdir comment above line, uncomment below one and replace <OSPOS path> with your path
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ospos/public/index.php?/$1 [L]

# disable directory browsing
# For security reasons, Option all cannot be overridden.
#Options All -Indexes
Options +ExecCGI +Includes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes

# prevent folder listing
IndexIgnore *

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule authz_core_module>
  # secure htaccess file
  <Files .htaccess>
    Require all denied
  </Files>
  # prevent access to PHP error log
  <Files error_log>
    Require all denied
  </Files>
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
  # secure htaccess file
  <Files .htaccess>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
  </Files>
  # prevent access to PHP error log
  <Files error_log>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
  </Files>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I have read many questions and made many tests, but I still haven't been able to figure out where and what to change to make it redirect correctly.

Anyone have any suggestions on this?
Thank you

PHP version: 7.3.13
MySQL version: 5.6.44-86.0
OS and version: CentOS 7
WebServer is: Apache 2.4

How should I edit:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public$   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge [NC]
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/public/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between relative and absolute paths In that configuration file inside the "ospos" folder you explicitly rewrite to the _absolute_ path `/public/`, so the browser will make a new request to exactly that, the absolute path inside the same http host, so `https://www.mysite.it/public/` ...

Comment: And you will probably have to add an exception for this path prefix in your WordPress .htaccess, otherwise that will catch any requests for non-existing resources underneath /ospos/ already.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha for the suggestions, but how can I get www.mysite.com/ospos/public to point as an absolute pat? How should I edit:    "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public$   
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge [NC]
          RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/public/" [R=301,L] "

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public$   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge [NC]
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/public/" [R=301,L]
```

Should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public$   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge [NC]
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/ospos/public/" [R=301,L]
```